# PHP Trims last square bracket from ajax post

Tags: php, json, ajax, post, encoding

I have a form which looks something like this

```
<input value="2" type="number"  name="unit_id"  class="form-control unit-var ">
    <input value="200" type="number"  name="values[x]"  class="form-control unit-var ">
    <input value="300" type="number"  name="values[y]"  class="form-control unit-var ">
    <input value="400" type="number"  name="values[z]"  class="form-control unit-var ">
```

Im using jquery ajax function to collect all the information, and post it to my php script

the function looks like this

```
var units = {};

$('.form-control').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()){
        units[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  }
});

$.post('/url/',units,function(response){
        console.log(response);
});
```

The problem that I'm having is, for some reason the last square bracket gets removed, so the key  `values` now becomes a variable. This is what my `$_REQUEST` variable holds (I've excluded other input fields):

```
 values[x = "164"
 values[y = "142"
 values[z = "300"
```

has anybody came across something like this before and if so what em I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you check :var_dump($_POST['values']);? Are you sure there are no other inputs in the page with the class 'form-control' that are not correct?

Comment: Shows the same thing             ''values[x' => string '164' (length=3)
      'values[y' => string '142' (length=3)
      'values[z' => string '300' (length=3)'  . And yes im confident, before the data gets submitted via ajax, I've checked the units variable in js and the values were named correctly

Comment: Do a `console.log(units)` and make sure it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: console.log(units) does hold the correct values with all the brackets, however one thing I'm wondering is should it be shown as separate variables or as an array when i do console.log() ?

Comment: Something must be wrong with your inputs, check this https://plnkr.co/edit/Z430Q198bEjIZdlZxKmV?p=preview  do notice in the console you have a request(invalid) but correct post variables -> `{unit_id: "2", values[x]: "200", values[y]: "300", values[z]: "400"}`

Comment: That is what I thought, a mispell or something like that, but this is what i see from post data form data in google dev tools headers:  values[x]:164
values[y]:142
values[z]:300

Comment: So from what I understand it leaves the client with correct information, but right at the beginning of the php script it comes in without the brackets. I was wondering moment ago if it could be something todo with specific php version or my server config, but I've tried this on two different servers...